# How to show progress of r code in spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire

Has anyone found a way to show the progress of an r code inside spotfire. For example how for it has gotten inside a for loop. So the code would look something like this in r outside of spotfire:

```
total <- 20
# create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
for(i in 1:total){
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
   # update progress bar
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
   i
}
```

I am having trouble thinking up of a solution, since spotfire doesnt output text until the program is finished. The example above fails to produce anything that can be observed. Any ideas for how to see the output text from the r code while it is running in spotfire or creating a progress bar will be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see a way to show the progress bar real time. But if you want to get an idea of the timing of your code execution (after it's finished) you could put some old-fashioned print statement in your loop, such as print(paste(i,Sys.time())) and enable data function debugging through Tools>Options>Data functions>Enable data function debugging. Once your data function has finished running, you can see what's been printed from the Notification panel: a yellow warning dot appears to show that there is data function debug output. I am not sure in which version of Spotfire this options was introduced. P.S. in your original code the progress bar can be printed by substituting print(i) to i, but it does not really render properly within TERR/Spotfire, the segment is always of the same length. I have not tried playing with progress bar options.

Answer (score 1):

R code is run in another process, and the result is sent to spotfire at the end of the execution. Thus you can't have a progress bar using one script.

The only way to do this is by having multiple scripts that update a document property `txtProgressBar`, but note that it makes your spotfire application **heavily not maintainable**. Each script should be responsible of a part of the job, and should have a dummy document property. Each document property should be set as an output of a script, and as input of the next one. Each script should be set with autorefresh, and should update the document property to launch automatically the next one.